# Удаление элемента из Set Java ошибка

Tags: java, коллекции, foreach, итераторы, set

не могу понять почему прога компилируется но при запуске выдает ошибку

*Генерация коллекии сет
[65, 1, 97, 66, 2, 69, 6, 71, 42, 14, 49, 19, 83, 20, 21, 53, 56, 59, 92, 29]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1584)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1607)
at JavaRushLect8.Collections.main(Collections.java:189)*



public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Set<Integer> setOfInteger = new HashSet<>();
        randomInsert(setOfInteger, 20, 100);
      
        for (int i : setOfInteger) {
            if(i > 20)
            {
              setOfInteger.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Хотя если в блоке условия испоьзовать - System.out.println(i) все работает...

Comment: Не удаляйте из перебираемой коллекции элементы. Сделайте клон коллекции и удаляйте из клона.

Comment: Так себе решение. Вам к примеру надо удалить один элемент, а вы будете всю коллекцию копировать. А если в ней будет 100.000 элементов?

Comment: Можно использовать immutable (persistent) data structures (какую-то библиотеку).
Если реализовано structural sharing -- копироваnия 100.000 элементов не будет.

Comment: Постарайтесь вообще не менять структуры, которые читаете, по возможности. Читаете/перебираете одно -- пишите в другое. Меньше багов будет.

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет...

Answer (score 3):

Удалять элементы коллекции в процессе ее перебора нельзя.

Я бы предложил 2 варианта:

```
Set<Integer> result = setOfInteger.stream().filter(i -> i <= 20).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

В этом случае создается новая коллекция result с уже отфильтрованными значениями.

А если вам принципиально нужно удалить элементы из исходной коллекции (это лучше не делать, но все же), то на помощь придет итератор:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = setOfInteger.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (iterator.next() > 20) iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало... прибегнул к итератору, толко начинаю учить програмирование 2ую неделю, туплю жестко местами )))

Comment: Вариант с `filter` лучше -- безопаснее. `iterator.remove` используйте только если действительно нужна оптимизация.

Answer (score 1):

Немного продолжу ответ [Дмитрия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/269255/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9).

В Java 8 в классе Collection появился метод `removeIf()`, который удаляет элемент из коллекции по условию. Под капотом он использует всё тот же Iterator, просто он позволяет вам писать меньше кода. Этот метод вызывается у коллекции *(Set в том числе)*, и в него передаётся предикат. Что такое предикат - читайте про функциональные интерфейсы и лямбды.

Вот пример Дмитрия:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = setOfInteger.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (iterator.next() > 20) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

А вот как выглядит использование метода `removeIf()`:

```
setOfInteger.removeIf(num -> num > 20);
```

По-моему намного приятней.

Ещё Дмитрий писал в ответе:

> А если вам принципиально нужно удалить элементы из исходной коллекции
> (это лучше не делать, но все же)

Я лишь немного скажу об этом. Например, сейчас я решал такую задачу: выгружал из базы данных сущность, которая содержит Set. Так вот, если этот Set пересоздать *(удалив при этом элемент)*, то Hibernate выбросит ошибку, потому что он отслеживает этот Set. Поэтому иногда надо удалять элемент напрямую из коллекции, не пересоздавая её.

Answer (score 0):

Вы удаляет перебирая индекс по возрастанию. Представьте вы удалили 99 и следующий хотите удалить 100 откуда ему взяться если после удаления 99 у вас в сете осталось 99. Удаляют из коллекций индексируя по убыванию. Так чтоб не возращяться к проверенным элементам.

А вернуть индекс не удаляя ничего с чего там должна быть ошибка?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, дало некоторое понимание...

Comment: Это иллюстрация, показывающая, какого типа проблеммы и почему бывают. И как их можно решить в каком-то другом случае. Конкретно `HashSet` в java не гарантирует порядка перебора (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) "elements are returned in no particular order"